# Class initialization fails with default constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, heap-memory

I am learning about classes in C++ and I created a simple one that just creates an interval from int a to int b, using a dynamic int array. Here's the code:

```
Interval::Interval() {
    a_ = 0;
    b_ = 0;
    interval = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; ++i) {
        interval[i] = 0;
    }
}

Interval::Interval(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) Interval(); // doesn't seem to work?

    else if (a == b) {
        a_ = a;
        b_ = b;
        interval = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; ++i) {
            interval[i] = a;
        }
    } else {
        a_ = a;
        b_ = b;
        int size = b - a + 1;
        interval = new int[size]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            interval[i] = a++;
        }
    }
}

Interval::~Interval() {
    delete[] interval;
    cout << "Destructed\n";
}
```

However, on this part here:

> if (a > b) Interval();

It doesn't seem to create it. Where am I wrong?

Edit: As answered by molbdnilo, I was simply creating a separate object inside of the scope of the constructor without assigning or doing anything with it.

Comment: What do you expect that `if (a > b) Interval();` should do? (It creates an object that is not used immediately destructed at the end of the `if`)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `interval` should be simply `int interval[2];`. No need for dynamic allocation here. Also, loops are usually written `for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)`. The loops as written work correctly, but most readers will pause for a moment, asking why it's written that way.

Comment: Yes, good point. @t.niese I want default constructed object in that case. How do I do without writing the same piece of code again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that your default constructor is equivalent to `Interval(0,0)`, you can reuse the non-default constructor instead, by forwarding to it:

```
Interval::Interval() : Interval(0,0) {}


Interval::Interval(int a, int b) 
    : a_(a <= b ? a : 0),
      b_(a <= b ? b : 0)
 {
    if (a_ == b_) {
        interval = new int[2] {a_, a_};
    } else {
        int size = b_ - a_ + 1;
        interval = new int[size]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            interval[i] = a_ + i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
if (a > b) Interval();
```

when the condition is met, it default constructs a temporary `Interval` which is destroyed at the end of the line.

Your code looks rather compilcated for what it does. The array should rather be a `std::vector` such that you need not mess around with manual memory allocations. Anyhow, to get what you want "I want default constructed object in that case." the easy fix is the following:

```
if (a > b) {
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
}

if (a == b) {
    a_ = a;
    b_ = b;
    interval = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; ++i) {
        interval[i] = a;
    }
} else { ...
```

Comment: For an array that always has two elements, I wouldn't use `std::vector`.   I'd use either a `std::array` or a raw array.

Comment: @Peter i thought so too, but it does not always have two elements. When `a <b` OP is filling the array with all integers from a to b.